# Flutter: Is the Column widget constrained or unconstrained vertically?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Should we consider the `Column` widget constrained or unconstrained in the vertical direction?

According to the document of the `Column` widget:

> When the contents of a Column exceed the amount of space available,
>   the Column overflows, and the contents are clipped.

To my understanding, this means that the Column widget is constrained (or bounded) vertically.

On the other hand, the documentation of the `Center` widget says:

> If a dimension is unconstrained and the corresponding size factor is
>   null then the widget will match its child's size in that dimension.

When I place the `Center` widget in the children of a `Column`, what happens is that the `Center` widget shrinks its height to match the height of its child. According to the above document, this means that the `Column` widget is unconstrained in the vertical direction.

So which take is correct? Is the `Column` widget constrained or unconstrained in the vertical direction?

Answer (score 8):

I think you're mixing the parent constraints with the children constraints.

The box constraints that the column itself receives from its parent is different from the one it passes on to its children: the column may be constrained in height by its parent, but it gives its children an infinite (unconstrained) height. Therefore..

> To my understanding, this means that the Column widget is constrained (or bounded) vertically.

Yes, the column is constrained by its parent.

> According to the above document, this means that the Column widget is unconstrained in the vertical direction.

Not the column itself but its children, on the other hand, are not constrained in height. This explains why the `Center` shrinks on the vertical direction to match its child.